# How to render multiple value inside single Colum in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

This is my render code function which is working

```
        {
            "data": "assignedTo",
 
            "render": function (data) {
               

                var btnDetail = "<a  href='/Ticket/TicketDetail?ticketId=" + data + "'>" + data + "</a>";
                return btnDetail;
            }

        },
```

However I want something like

```
 var btnDetail = "<a  href='/Ticket/TicketDetail?ticketId=" + data + "'>" + data + "</a>";
```

where user can see assignedTo but when they click it should got to the ticketId. In short i want both ticketId and assignedTo value in single colum. Please guide me.

Comment: what's the values of your `data` object?

Comment: Either `data` or value from `render` will be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of `row` parameter from `render` function. It contains all values available for current row.

> `row` The full data source for the row (not based on [`columns.data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data))

[Read more about column rendering here.](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render)

```
{
    data: 'assignedTo',
    render: function (data, type, row) {
       var btnDetail = "<a href='/Ticket/TicketDetail?ticketId=" + row.TicketId + "'>" + data + "</a>";
       return btnDetail;
    }
}
```

or you can ignore `data` completely if you want to use `render` function.

```
{
    data: null,
    render: function (data, type, row) {
       var btnDetail = "<a href='/Ticket/TicketDetail?ticketId=" + row.TicketId + "'>" + row.assignedTo + "</a>";
       return btnDetail;
    }
}
```

All other values returned from server will be available through `row` parameter.